# Nodeos unlinkable_block_exception

Tags: nodeos, mainnet

I'm currently trying to run WAX Mainnet locally but was getting unlinkable_block_exception. I tried to sync from different snapshots but was getting the same error. Starting from a genesis file didn't give me the error at the beginning but once it reached around 9 million it started to give the error as well.

I also tried many versions of Nodeos, from 2.0 to 2.2 but same issue.

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

```
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.126 net-2     net_plugin.cpp:1209           _close               ] closing 'waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877', waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.126 net-2     net_plugin.cpp:1409           operator()           ] async write socket closed before callback: waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.126 net-2     net_plugin.cpp:1336           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877, lib 142457091, head 142457091, id 9d6f029491df1747
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.126 net-2     net_plugin.cpp:1209           _close               ] closing 'waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877', waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.126 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:1409           operator()           ] async write socket closed before callback: waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.126 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:1209           _close               ] closing 'waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877', waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.227 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:2605           operator()           ] host: waxp2p.ledgerwise.io port: 21877
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.227 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:3676           connection_monitor   ] p2p client connections: 0/100, peer connections: 21/21
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.331 net-2     net_plugin.cpp:1336           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877, lib 142457091, head 142457091, id 9d6f029491df1747
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.484 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:1997           start_sync           ] Catching up with chain, our last req is 0, theirs is 147975642 peer waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.484 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:1943           operator()           ] requesting range 142457092 to 142457591, from waxp2p.ledgerwise.io:21877
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.484 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:3195           handle_message       ] Local network version: 5 Remote version: 1
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.484 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2057           recv_handshake       ] handshake from 0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76, lib 147975642, head 147975978, head id 0453a093fe5a0547.. sync 1
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.485 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:1336           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 2 to 0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76, lib 142457091, head 142457091, id 9d6f029491df1747
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.613 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:1997           start_sync           ] Catching up with chain, our last req is 142457591, theirs is 147975642 peer 0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.613 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:1864           request_next_chunk   ] ignoring request, head is 142457091 last req = 142457591 source is 0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76
error 2021-10-28T17:11:53.725 nodeos    controller.cpp:1741           apply_block          ] *trace: {"id":"84b7f4624ac9a2f1984a66b249994ea4ab05894ed5da950b812bdd4694844ed1","block_num":142457092,"block_time":"2021-09-26T18:03:18.000","producer_block_id":"087db904b42abcd42a85c1c42b8b48a209cad8fe7b45917c3db37950149d99b8","elapsed":1915,"net_usage":1127,"scheduled":false,"action_traces":[{"action_ordinal":1,"creator_action_ordinal":0,"closest_unnotified_ancestor_action_ordinal":0,"receiver":"orng.wax","act":{"account":"orng.wax","name":"setrand","authorization":[{"actor":"oracle.wax","permission":"rngops"}],"data":"f6ab6f0000000000800862656162613436353861663231326235633162653034323133336265633864316137343661363336326663386137663832396365313564373563306664393731643037303039656631326338393838613733643463613032373835393030393065623762623765626566333566646432326265663337333563656363626435363838643830323036386236643561333766383163323837663838323532323666356533616130323930613461666364313630343339653630393936343966633061643931306432393034363561313132363339353966373935383563636239666432653334653731616162346462646232646335316262616630663638376664646237396634353763363635316264653136626262393133376339313264666464313930646362373633626634616236623232386432643934653934643861396365343035643965343865323664333934363336623635386432306130616364383036616366613965396231613437303264386261313138313931613065366635306466343330663066383230373234633165363232633763386361666630363966633132316561326163356334646263333530363161346533626164376334306433313237313337356537653361643838396337653830626166373033336161386334336565613139383833333533633831663033376665656161613831333861653534356638666362356561323932666530626132663263666466663864393531666461663431353263666437323632633932346135386361323530363862316235353861343433646238633431363038633863623436326135393434623464366535396632666635663436336334373166323237653637346165626462323634343434393833353137323338666439613061366162396234626136663833613366386264316134383963663163303163623535656461626630646433393966343931656437393636313337313037323737346130666136663336313236663738656263303832353631393633613034353230366238636438653338336263313735323161643432356133383837666637366565313439643539666239363066303335326561633532643561666163303133613736613364343433373161633633663331333065666235643334383237383834333363653262323534613932643934346130373538343862653862373161646139616461386634336338313331363361626433613762653564393733666463313139663161323739653862396363366438393565386339623739333237386338316638636265303931356331343534666164356261646565313430356130363964353564633766383830363839343335656465356665383863316234666537623965663532623536633331"},"context_free":false,"elapsed":1839,"console":"","trx_id":"84b7f4624ac9a2f1984a66b249994ea4ab05894ed5da950b812bdd4694844ed1","block_num":142457092,"block_time":"2021-09-26T18:03:18.000","producer_block_id":"087db904b42abcd42a85c1c42b8b48a209cad8fe7b45917c3db37950149d99b8","account_ram_deltas":[],"account_disk_deltas":[],"except":{"code":3070002,"name":"wasm_execution_error","message":"Runtime Error Processing WASM","stack":[{"context":{"level":"error","file":"eos-vm.cpp","line":191,"method":"instantiate_module","hostname":"","thread_name":"nodeos","timestamp":"2021-10-28T17:11:53.725"},"format":"Error building eos-vm interp: ${e}","data":{"e":"wasm linked function failure"}},{"context":{"level":"warn","file":"apply_context.cpp","line":143,"method":"exec_one","hostname":"","thread_name":"nodeos","timestamp":"2021-10-28T17:11:53.725"},"format":"pending console output: ${console}","data":{"console":""}}]},"error_code":"10000000000000000000","return_value":""}],"failed_dtrx_trace":null,"except":{"code":3070002,"name":"wasm_execution_error","message":"Runtime Error Processing WASM","stack":[{"context":{"level":"error","file":"eos-vm.cpp","line":191,"method":"instantiate_module","hostname":"","thread_name":"nodeos","timestamp":"2021-10-28T17:11:53.725"},"format":"Error building eos-vm interp: ${e}","data":{"e":"wasm linked function failure"}},{"context":{"level":"warn","file":"apply_context.cpp","line":143,"method":"exec_one","hostname":"","thread_name":"nodeos","timestamp":"2021-10-28T17:11:53.725"},"format":"pending console output: ${console}","data":{"console":""}}]},"error_code":"10000000000000000000","bill_to_accounts":[]}
error 2021-10-28T17:11:53.725 nodeos    controller.cpp:1783           apply_block          ] e.to_detail_string(): 3070002 wasm_execution_error: Runtime Error Processing WASM
Error building eos-vm interp: wasm linked function failure
    {"e":"wasm linked function failure"}
    nodeos  eos-vm.cpp:191 instantiate_module
pending console output:
    {"console":""}
    nodeos  apply_context.cpp:143 exec_one

warn  2021-10-28T17:11:53.725 nodeos    controller.cpp:1864           push_block           ] 3070002 wasm_execution_error: Runtime Error Processing WASM
Error building eos-vm interp: wasm linked function failure
    {"e":"wasm linked function failure"}
    nodeos  eos-vm.cpp:191 instantiate_module
pending console output:
    {"console":""}
    nodeos  apply_context.cpp:143 exec_one

    {}
    nodeos  controller.cpp:1791 apply_block

error 2021-10-28T17:11:53.725 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:384       operator()           ] 3070002 wasm_execution_error: Runtime Error Processing WASM
Error building eos-vm interp: wasm linked function failure
    {"e":"wasm linked function failure"}
    nodeos  eos-vm.cpp:191 instantiate_module
pending console output:
    {"console":""}
    nodeos  apply_context.cpp:143 exec_one

    {}
    nodeos  controller.cpp:1791 apply_block
rethrow
    {}
    nodeos  controller.cpp:1864 push_block

error 2021-10-28T17:11:53.725 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:3529           process_signed_block ] ["0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76" 157.90.91.224:21877] bad block exception #142457092 b42abcd42a85c1c4...: Runtime Error Processing WASM (3070002)
Error building eos-vm interp: wasm linked function failure
pending console output:

rethrow

error 2021-10-28T17:11:53.726 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:3521           process_signed_block ] ["0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76" 157.90.91.224:21877] unlinkable_block_exception #142457093 40e2b0a8ec2b4e8c...: Unlinkable block (3030001)
unlinkable block 087db90540e2b0a8ec2b4e8ce847ceb5ab990c5cd0d74f1f99b007f59c6177ad

info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.726 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:1336           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 3 to 0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76, lib 142457091, head 142457091, id 9d6f029491df1747
info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.726 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:1336           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 4 to 0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76, lib 142457091, head 142457091, id 9d6f029491df1747
error 2021-10-28T17:11:53.821 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:3521           process_signed_block ] ["0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76" 157.90.91.224:21877] unlinkable_block_exception #142457094 aebd664f88044848...: Unlinkable block (3030001)
unlinkable block 087db906aebd664f88044848bd20e6400b5ce1bdee6ae1f294de022ac0469d15

info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.821 net-2     net_plugin.cpp:1336           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 5 to 0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76, lib 142457091, head 142457091, id 9d6f029491df1747
error 2021-10-28T17:11:53.829 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:3521           process_signed_block ] ["0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76" 157.90.91.224:21877] unlinkable_block_exception #142457095 c50161f3dc48cb64...: Unlinkable block (3030001)
unlinkable block 087db907c50161f3dc48cb64879cc98cee3ad5bb5aaa66dd264ddd6c134de986

info  2021-10-28T17:11:53.830 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:1336           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 6 to 0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76, lib 142457091, head 142457091, id 9d6f029491df1747
error 2021-10-28T17:11:53.924 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:3521           process_signed_block ] ["0.0.0.0:21976 - a0b3e76" 157.90.91.224:21877] unlinkable_block_exception #142457096 862fd045730cf8b3...: Unlinkable block (3030001)
```

Info from my config file:

```
wasm-runtime = eos-vm-jit
chain-state-db-size-mb = 58368
eos-vm-oc-compile-threads = 4
database-map-mode = heap
trace-history = true
chain-state-history = true
enable-account-queries = true

plugin = eosio::http_plugin
plugin = eosio::state_history_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the wax binaries?  wax doesn't work with standard eosio binaries.

Comment: Using wax binaries solved the issue. Thank you very much!